# How to add new custom row in each group in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need a help to add a new row for each group in my jqGird.
I've already added a custom row in the code below in my grid, but I need to add a new row in each group.

How can I add it ?

Currently I'm adding this code to create a group.

```
groupField : ['title'],
groupColumnShow : [true],
groupText : ['<b>{0}</b><img src="/plus.png" onclick="javascript:loadNewGridRow(mygridname)" title="Add Row">'],
groupCollapse : false,
groupDataSorted : true
```

At a time when I click on my image then one row is added last on my grid, but I need to add a new row for each group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The requirement "to add a new row for **each** group" sounds strange. Moreover, it's important that you post some additional information about the usage of jqGrid: do you use local data or makes grouping on the server side? which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) and soon. In general, you can just add the row to the grid data, but with the data correspond grouping value. After that you can reload the grid.

Comment: Hi Oleg,
i am using jqGrid  4.4.3 - jQuery Grid and used server data also i am using official JqGrid.
I am also using add new row at botom of grid.but need to add new row in each group.

Comment: You should include *more JavaScript code* in the text of your question to show how you use jqGrid. Moreover, you can try to add `$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid")` at the end of code of `loadNewGridRow`. It will reload the data (or the page of data) and to display new row on the correct place. Finally, I'd strictly recommend you to upgrade retro version 4.4.3 (it's 5.5 year old) to the latest free jqGrid 4.15.5 (which I develop) or to the latest version of commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.3.1. The version 4.4.3 is out of any support since many years.

Comment: Hi Oleg Thanks for reply.
May be add 'new row for each group' not possible in JQGrid. 
So i need to add new custom code for each group on click (group name) and open this group (with all row data behalf of group name) on popup with new grid, then add new row for this group on bottom. I am using same approach for each group.